# Note 8 lock screen PIN differs from startup?

Tags: security, lock-screens

I'm trying to fix a Note 8 that seems to be in a weird state. The correct PIN should be 4 digits. The lock screen won't accept the PIN (the OK button stays greyed out until I hit 6 digits, at which time it reports that the pin is invalid). But it seems to be the correct pin, as it works to decrypt the phone on startup.

The phone user says the only unusual thing they did before the problem occurred was to reset their Secure Folder password. They said that they were able to get into Secure Folder after the reset. Their secure folder password does not work to unlock the lock screen. Later, after the screen turned off, they were unable to unlock the phone.

I'm totally mystified. Can the startup and lock screen pins be different? If they can, can the problem be corrected somehow, or does the phone need to be reset?

Comment: They can be different upto lollipop if your device is rooted and using apps to do that. In later versions is not possible AFAIK. Given the way Samsung implementation is different from stock, it's probably best to reset